# Microsoft project resource allocation

Tags: ms-project

Is it possible to allocate work on Microsoft Project on a 30min accuracy? Basically i want to allocate:

Jane: Task 1, 08:00am - 9:30am

Judy: Task 2, 10:30:am - 1:00pm

Therefore i want to tell them what to do on a half hour accuracy. How can this be done?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

MS Project allows time increments as low as a minute. By default the task duration unit is in days but that can be changed. The documentation shows [how to change it](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/change-the-default-task-duration-unit-af79599d-29e8-4e77-86a7-77c37410155e).

1. On the **File** tab, click **Options**.
2. In the **Project Options** dialogue box, click **Schedule**.
3. Under **Scheduling options for this project**, in the **Duration is entered in** list, select a duration unit.

[image: Change the default task duration unit]